# Should I use delegation or an alternative pattern?

Tags: ios, design-patterns, timer

I'm developing an interval timer fitness app for iPhone while learning OOP. The main timer object has to be able to notify any other interested objects of events, such as switching to a new interval or timer finishing, etc.

My first thought was to use delegation, but I want multiple objects to be able to be notified of these events, and it's not really delegating any work, it's just notifying them... So this doesn't seem right.

Can anyone else suggest another pattern/ approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should us [Key-Value-Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html), the cocoa-flavored [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), if the reciever knows the sender, so that he can turn in on its notifications.

if this is not given, the more decoupled [NSNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i) would be an option, as the sender does not need to know the object sending the notifications.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a good candidate for `NSNotificationCenter` (event / subscriber pattern)

Answer (score 1):

[**Notifications Pattern**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html)

> The notification mechanism of Cocoa implements one-to-many broadcast of messages based on the Observer pattern. Objects in a program add themselves or other objects to a list of observers of one or more notifications, each of which is identified by a global string (the notification name). The object that wants to notify other objects—the observed object—creates a notification object and posts it to a notification center. The notification center determines the observers of a particular notification and sends the notification to them via a message.